# Retrieving list of SMS Conversational partners via Twilio C# API

Tags: c#, twilio, twilio-api

I'm using the Twilio C# helper library in my SMS .NET project successfully, but I have a performance/optimization question:

Currently, in order to refresh my app's list of unique conversational partners, I'm basically returning a date-filtered list via MessageResource.Read like:

```
MessageResource.Read(dateSentAfter:=New DateTime(DatePart(DateInterval.Year, dtOldestMessageDate), DatePart(DateInterval.Month, dtOldestMessageDate), DatePart(DateInterval.Day, dtOldestMessageDate), 0, 0, 0))
```

...just so I can compile a list of the unique conversational partners by juggling/sorting the resulting list.

Given that I could have **many** messages to/from any/all partner(s), it seems rather inefficient.

Is there a method I'm missing that could simply return a list of unique conversational partners' phone numbers and the datetime of the last SMS (in or out) with them?

Answer (score 0):

Below are the best practices for SMS logging, I would suggest maintaining the logs on your side/in your data store, rather than having Twilio store them and using the REST API to obtain them.

[Best Practices for SMS Message Logging - Recommendations for maintaining messaging records](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/outbound-message-logging)